# How to compare dates to see where adjacent times meet?

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, date-sorting

I have dates currently formatted in the following way:

```
[ [ Tue Jun 17 2014 09:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    Tue Jun 17 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ] ]

[ [ Thu Jun 19 2014 09:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    Thu Jun 19 2014 11:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ] ]

[ [ Tue Jun 17 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    Tue Jun 17 2014 11:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ] ]
```

These dates are actually "sessions", and I need to see where certain sessions are adjacent to each other. For example, in this specific case, the first array of dates has a end time of 10AM while the last array of dates has a start time for 10AM. How can I computationally find this situation?

The one approach I have is to first sort the array sets from earliest time to to latest time, and then compare each of the start/end date pairs to see if they are the same, but I can't seem to get it through. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: If two dates are exactly the same, then their values in ms must match. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Right now I am undergoing an attempt where I iterate over the dates to find matches, and thought I could just try comparing the date object themselves. I'll try getting their MS values and comparing them! @elclanrs

Comment: The objects are different but the values must be the same http://jsbin.com/qipos/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the strings into Unix timestamps with `Date.parse()` (if these are actually `Date` objects, then use the `.getTime()` method) and then order the sessions with `Array.prototype.sort()`. Here's an example where the sessions are ordered by start time:

```
var sessions = [
    ["Tue Jun 17 2014 09:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)", "Tue Jun 17 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"],
    ["Thu Jun 19 2014 09:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)", "Thu Jun 19 2014 11:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"],
    ["Tue Jun 17 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)", "Tue Jun 17 2014 11:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"]
];

for (var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
    sessions[i].startTime= Date.parse(sessions[i][0]);
}

sessions.sort(function(a, b) { return a.startTime-b.startTime; });
```